# Ember: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js

How does one target the element that an event occurred on in Ember?  I thought the proper place for events was in a templates `controller` but is that incorrect?

The error I am getting when I lick in a list-item is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined`

Here is a fiddle to my code:  http://jsfiddle.net/za1r2o5u/

Here is my JS:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

var json_data = [
    {"color": "red"},
    {"color": "blue"}
];

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route("index", {path: '/'});
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return json_data;
    }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        clickMe: function(event) {
            // How do I log the target element?  This is throwing an error
            console.log(event.target);
        }
    }
});
```

Here is my templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2> Welcome to Ember.js</h2>
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <h2>Inside Index</h2>

    <ul>
        {{#each model}}
            <li {{bind-attr class=color}} {{action 'clickMe'}}>Click here: {{color}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

Comment: What are you planning to do with the target once you get it? The normal Ember way would be `{{action 'clickMe' this}}`, which would pass the model instance to the action. Ember does not pass the event to the action in the way you are expecting.

Comment: Eventually I'll be looking to lazy load some data. I have been trying to learn Ember though and this is my first go around with the `actions` property Now I'm just wondering how to best handle events that will update the DOM.

Comment: The DOM is constructed in real-time by the template. To "handle events that will update the DOM", you respond to the event by changing model and controller properties, and they are automatically reflected in the DOM. Dealing directly with DOM elements is a "code smell" in emberland.

Comment: Ok.  What I would eventually like to do is lazy load a tree list of items.  So clicking on an item would result in an ajax call to load child items which would be placed in a `<ul>` within the `<li>` that is clicked.  Just starting out, targeting the element that was clicked seemed like something that should be simple though I was mistaken in that.

Comment: The way you do this in Ember is to add a `<ul>{{#each items}}<li>...</li>{{/each}}</ul>` to your template inside the `<li>`, then when the `items` property on the model instance is populated, they will magically appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native `event` objects from the DOM are available in `view` and `components` (subclasses of view):

http://jsfiddle.net/samselikoff/za1r2o5u/5/

As @torazaburo mentioned, for the purposes you're describing you probably don't want to do this. To "lazy load" data, in your template you'll have something like this

```
{{#each item in items}}
  <!-- template markup -->
{{/each>>
```

and whenever `items` is populated, the template will update. To update the `items` data, you may use an action elsewhere in your template:

```
<button {{action 'getItems'}}>Get items</button>
```

and handle the action on your route:

```
//routes/some-route.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    getItems: function() {
      var _this = this;

      return Ember.$.getJSON('items', function(items) {
        _this.controller.set('items', items);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

then your template will update automatically.

Comment: Thank you!  I wish I could give more up votes for the wonderful explanation!

Comment: This may be a question for another post, but I'm wondering if it is necessary to have the action in the `<button {{action 'getItems}}>` element.  For a tree list each item could have many children, so could the same effect be done when attaching the action to each `<li>`?

Comment: Sure, you can `<li {{action 'whatever' arg}}>`